# Socket Property Of Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am currently trying to make a real time chat room using node, express, and socket.io. When I run the code, I get this error message:
http://gyazo.com/d9956a80a691d1642b438173b0bd85bf

Also, here is my index.js code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3700;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.set("views", __dirname + "/tpl");
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.engine("jade", require("jade").__express);
app.get("/", function (req, res){
    res.render("page");
});

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket){
    socket.emit("message", { message: "welcome to the chat" });
    socket.on("send", function (data){
        io.sockets.emit("message", data);
    });
});

var io = require("socket.io").listen(app.listen(port));
console.log("Listening On Port " + port);
```

I have searched up over google and found no solutions that were related to my code. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the io variable before it's initialized move the var io before the io.sockets

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(app.listen(port));
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket){
    socket.emit("message", { message: "welcome to the chat" });
    socket.on("send", function (data){
        io.sockets.emit("message", data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a variable before it's declared and your `listen()` calls look kind of strange.

Instead of doing this:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket){
  socket.emit("message", { message: "welcome to the chat" });
  socket.on("send", function (data){
    io.sockets.emit("message", data);
  });
});

var io = require("socket.io").listen(app.listen(port));
```

You should do something more like this:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(app);

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket){
  socket.emit("message", { message: "welcome to the chat" });
  socket.on("send", function (data){
    io.sockets.emit("message", data);
  });
});

app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `io` variable before it is initialized.

Simply move the following line (`io` variable initialization):

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(app.listen(port));
```

Before the first use of `io` variable at this line:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket){
```